# Binding validation script to form within jQuery Facebox plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, bind, facebox

I'm making a little "you give me your email, I'll give you an AWESOME song" page for a mate's band. I'm trying to get the simple javascript form (email) validation to work when submitting from with in the jQuery Facebox plugin. I've found out that you need to bind the JS validation function *after* the Facebox has opened or it doesn't work. The basis for doing that is laid out with in the Facebox documentation and should go something like this: `$(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() { ...stuff to do after the facebox and contents are revealed... })`.  As mentioned below, I didn't think this should be the case as I thought Facebox only showed a hidden element encased in the Facebox CSS parameters but it definitely needs to be bound to the event handler only when the Facebox is opened.

Well it turns out I just cannot get it to work (except in Firefox which meant debugging with Firebug was a bit of a no go!) - you can put any old gumpf into the email form and submit it and it happily sends a confirmation to "asdsdf" or whatever I typed in at the time.

The code is below, I'd really appreciate *any* help on this!

Thanks for your time.

Rich

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title>Track download</title> 
    <meta name="image:Background" content="images/background.jpg" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset-min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="facebox.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebox.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox();
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function validateForm(){       
        var x=document.forms["emailForm"]["emailAddress"].value;
        var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <h1>Gorgeous George</h1><br /> 
        <h2><a href="#user" rel="facebox">Download</a> our new track!</h2><br /><br /> 
        <p>Follow us on <a href="http://gorgeousgeorgetheband.tumblr.com" target="_blank">Tumblr</a></p> 
        <p>Follow us on <a href="http://soundcloud.com/gorgeous-george-the-band" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a></p> 

            <div id="user"> 
                <form action="index.php" method="post" name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();"> 
                <fieldset> 
                    <h3 class="black">Email Address:</h3><br /> 
                    <input id="emailAddress" id="emailForm" name="emailAddress" onfocus="(this.value == &quot;Enter Email Address&quot;) ? this.value = &quot;&quot; : this.value" size="30" type="text" value="Enter Email Address" width="28" /><br /> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </form> 
            </div>        <img src="images/gorgeousGeorge.jpg" alt="Gorgeous George" class="mainImage" /> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Q mentioned that facebox creates a copy of the elements, so to refer to any element in the window, I gave everything a class instead of an id then referred to it thus:

```
$($('.email')[1])
```

Then, unfortunately, I had to roll my own validation because any plugin still didn't work. Here's one example:

```
if($($('.email')[1]).val().length <= 0){
    return false;
}
```

Kind of a hack, but hope that helps.

Comment: class instead of id ... what a numpty I am

Answer (score 1):

Facebox makes a copy of whatever page element you point it to... it doesn't just hide/show that page element with extra css treatment to make it look like a modal.

For example, if you have a form with id='x', then after facebox runs you're actually going to have two forms with id='x' ... the one that facebox creates on the fly from your original ... and your original. In the DOM tree, the facebox element (the one the user sees) will be 2nd... and doesn't exist until facebox creates it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of Facebox, the contents of the modal window are always stored in the page but just hidden (by display: none) until required. Therefore you should not need to bind the validation after the facebox has loaded as the elements are in the DOM straight from page load.

With that in mind, try the following HTML. I've added in jQuery validate as it's easy to use and saves reinventing the wheel. And by wheel I mean email address format validation :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title> 
    <meta name="image:Background" content="images/background.jpg" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset-min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="facebox.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebox.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox();

            $("#user FORM").validate({
                rules: { 
                    emailAddress { required: true, email: true }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="wrapper"> 
        <h1>Gorgeous George</h1><br /> 
        <h2><a href="#user" rel="facebox">Download</a> our new track!</h2><br /><br /> 
        <p>Follow us on <a href="http://gorgeousgeorgetheband.tumblr.com" target="_blank">Tumblr</a></p> 
        <p>Follow us on <a href="http://soundcloud.com/gorgeous-george-the-band" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a></p> 

            <div id="user"> 
                <form action="index.php" method="post" name="emailForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();"> 
                <fieldset> 
                    <h3 class="black">Email Address:</h3><br /> 
                    <input id="emailAddress" id="emailForm" name="emailAddress" onfocus="(this.value == &quot;Enter Email Address&quot;) ? this.value = &quot;&quot; : this.value" size="30" type="text" value="Enter Email Address" width="28" /><br /> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                    </fieldset> 
                </form> 
            </div>        <img src="images/gorgeousGeorge.jpg" alt="Gorgeous George" class="mainImage" /> 
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

There's obvioulsy more ways to stylise the validation plugin, but this will at least work for you.

Comment: You'd have thought that were the case re: not needing to bind but it definitely is the case.  I've removed the facebox plugin and had the form show at page load and the validation works fine.  It's when I use the Facebox plugin on the div that some aspects of the way it renders the modal window effect the even handler.  I'm utterly stumped ...

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to call the form stored into a separate file, that way you won't have duplicates and then the script for validation will work with no issues, except... of course depending on how the error messages are being prompted to the user.